# average date for a group

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need help with the following query.

I have a table M which contains membre_number, first_name, Last_name, Date_birth.
I need to know how many members are older than the average of all the members first_name is Paul. please note that many members are named Paul.

I have tried the following

```
SELECT date_nais
  FROM membre
 WHERE prenom_membre = 'paul'

SELECT AVG(convert(GETDATE()-membre.date_nais)/365.242199)  
  FROM membre;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a homework completion service. You're going to need to do your own work. The [help/on-topic] says *Questions asking for homework help **must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.*** You've shown zero effort to solve the problem yourself. In addition, when you added the [tag:sql], you were shown a large box that suggested you also add a tag for the specific DBMS you're using, as there are differences. You chose to ignore that suggestion. Please read [ask].

Comment: Hint: You will need a [subquery](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189575(v=sql.105).aspx) to obtain the average. The subquery will need to be embedded in a main query's where clause in order to filter out the members who are younger than the subquery result.

Comment: Sorry @JohnWu, why a subquery is required here?

Answer (score 0):

Try it,

```
 DECLARE @M table
 (
 membre_number int identity, 
 first_name varchar(10), 
 Last_name varchar(10), 
 Date_birth date
 )

 INSERT @M (first_name, Last_name, Date_birth) Values 
 ('Paul', 'Surname 1' , '20170101')
 ,('dadada', 'Surname 1' , '20130101')
 ,('Paul', 'Surname 2' , '20090301')
 ,('Paul', 'Surname 3' , '19890401')
 ,('Paul', 'Surname 4' , '19300521')
  ,('Alana', 'XX' , '19750521')

 SELECT * 
 ,DATEDIFF(Year,Date_birth,Getdate()) Age
 ,Avg(Cast(DATEDIFF(Year,Date_birth,Getdate()) as decimal(5,2))) Over (Partition by first_name)  Agv_ByName
 ,Avg(Cast(DATEDIFF(Year,Date_birth,Getdate()) as decimal(5,2))) Over (Partition by 1) AllUsers
 ,Case when first_name = 'Paul' THEN 
            Avg(Cast(DATEDIFF(Year,Date_birth,Getdate()) as decimal(5,2))) Over (Partition by first_name) 
 Else NULL end Agv_Pauls_age
 FROM 
 @M
```

Result

```
membre_number first_name Last_name  Date_birth Age         Agv_ByName                              AllUsers                                Agv_Pauls_age
------------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------- --------------------------------------- --------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
6             Alana      XX         1975-05-21 42          42.000000                               28.166666                               NULL
2             dadada     Surname 1  2013-01-01 4           4.000000                                28.166666                               NULL
3             Paul       Surname 2  2009-03-01 8           30.750000                               28.166666                               30.750000
4             Paul       Surname 3  1989-04-01 28          30.750000                               28.166666                               30.750000
5             Paul       Surname 4  1930-05-21 87          30.750000                               28.166666                               30.750000
1             Paul       Surname 1  2017-01-01 0           30.750000                               28.166666                               30.750000

(6 rows affected)
```

Or it to have Paul AVg in all lines

```
;with cte as (

 SELECT * 
 ,DATEDIFF(Year,Date_birth,Getdate()) Age
 ,Avg(Cast(DATEDIFF(Year,Date_birth,Getdate()) as decimal(5,2))) Over (Partition by first_name)  Agv_ByName
 ,Avg(Cast(DATEDIFF(Year,Date_birth,Getdate()) as decimal(5,2))) Over (Partition by 1) AllUsers
 ,Case when first_name = 'Paul' THEN 
            Avg(Cast(DATEDIFF(Year,Date_birth,Getdate()) as decimal(5,2))) Over (Partition by first_name) 
 Else NULL end Agv_Pauls_age
 FROM 
 @M
 )
 SELECT 
  membre_number 
 ,first_name    
 ,Last_name 
 ,Date_birth    
 ,Age   
 ,Agv_ByName    
 ,AllUsers  
 ,MAX(IsNUll(Agv_Pauls_age,0)) Over (Partition By 1 ) Agv_Pauls_age
 from cte
```

Result

```
membre_number first_name Last_name  Date_birth Age         Agv_ByName                              AllUsers                                Agv_Pauls_age
------------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------- --------------------------------------- --------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
6             Alana      XX         1975-05-21 42          42.000000                               28.166666                               30.750000
2             dadada     Surname 1  2013-01-01 4           4.000000                                28.166666                               30.750000
3             Paul       Surname 2  2009-03-01 8           30.750000                               28.166666                               30.750000
4             Paul       Surname 3  1989-04-01 28          30.750000                               28.166666                               30.750000
5             Paul       Surname 4  1930-05-21 87          30.750000                               28.166666                               30.750000
1             Paul       Surname 1  2017-01-01 0           30.750000                               28.166666                               30.750000

(6 rows affected)
```

Comment: thank you for your help
now i need to count how many person above the average and i dont know how.